# Is there is a way to save data in React component when opening the link in another tab or browser?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm building a small React app that fetches news, display search results and goes to '/article/:id' for a specific article.
One of the requirements that I have - if the link ( '/article/:id') is copied and opened in another tab or browser, it should lead to a specific article, however, currently I'm losing the data when trying to open the link in another tab.
Is there is a way to save the data without fetching them again (I cannot fetch by id, as api doesn't provide id property)

This is how I currently pass data to my article component:

```
<Link
  to={`article/${i + 1}`}
  state={{
    ...
  }}
>
```

And receive via in article component via useLocation():
 `const { state } = useLocation()`